# Как заставить пулю лететь в двух направлениях правильно?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx

Собственно вопрос состоит в том, что бы заставить пулю лететь в двух направлениях по ширине относительно от самого игрока. Например если игрок стреляет вправо то пуля летит вправо если влево то летит влево... но у меня не выходит написать само условие правильно! получается что стрелять он стреляет все правильно, но стоит мне повернуть игрока в другую сторону и стрелять то те пули  которые летели в другой стороне разворачиваются и летят в том направлении куда стреляет игрок в данный момент и наоборот происходит тоже самое!
Имеется такой код...

Класс пуля `Bullet`:

```
public class Bullet {
    private Rectangle rect;
    private float velocity;

    public Bullet(Rectangle rect, float velocity) {
        this.rect = rect;
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public void updateRight() {
        rect.x += velocity;
    }

    public void updateLeft() {
        rect.x -= velocity;
    }

    public Rectangle getRect() {
        return rect;
    }

    public float getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }
}
```

Класс игрока где я пытаюсь написать условие(этот код находится в render методе):

```
if (arrayBullet.size != 0) {
    for (num = 0; num < arrayBullet.size; num++) {
    if (isShot) {
        arrayBullet.get(num).updateRight();
    }
    if (!isShot) {
        arrayBullet.get(num).updateLeft();
    }
```

И собственно сам выстрел воспроизводится в методе при нажатии кнопки:

```
    byte i = 0;
    if(facesRight){
        isShot=true;
    }
    else {
        isShot=false;
    }

    arrayBullet.add(new Bullet(new Rectangle(position.x, position.y + 0.3f, 0.7f, 0.7f), 0.3f));
```

Все это делается с помощью коллекции `ArrayList<Bullet>`

Comment: Если у Вас переменная, отвечающая за направление выстрела называется `isFire`, то разворачивающиеся пули - не главная Ваша проблема :).

Comment: скорость пули может быть отрицательной, тогда при прибавлении скорости к координате пуля будет лететь влево. два разных update не нужно.

Comment: @Igor я новичок в программировании мне простительно думаю.

Comment: @zRrr не могли бы вы написать как это должно выглядеть ? читая ваш комментарий не совсем понимаю. извините, что так... просто учусь программировать еще... мне нужно что бы пули летели по своим координатам и не знали друг о друге...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Движение пули после выстрела не должно зависеть от переменных, принадлежащих классу игрок.

```
public class Bullet {
    private Rectangle rect;
    private float velocity;

    public Bullet(Rectangle rect, float velocity) {
        this.rect = rect;
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public void move() {
        rect.x += velocity;
    }

    public Rectangle getRect() {
        return rect;
    }

    public float getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }
}

for (num = 0; num < arrayBullet.size; num++) {
    arrayBullet.get(num).move();
}

arrayBullet.add(new Bullet(
  new Rectangle(position.x, position.y + 0.3f, 0.7f, 0.7f), 
  facesRight? 0.3f : -0.3f
));
```

или

```
Rectangle bulletRectangle = new Rectangle(position.x, position.y + 0.3f, 0.7f, 0.7f);
float bulletVelocity = facesRight? 0.3f : -0.3f;

arrayBullet.add(new Bullet(bulletRectangle, bulletVelocity));
```

Comment: кошмар! все работает!!! спасибо вам! Игорь сколько лет вы программируете? откуда вы знали что именно так надо написать код??

Comment: и еще вопрос по этому коду... я не знал даже что можно такое условие писать внутри конструктора! facesRight? 0.3f : -0.3f)  я блин неделю голову ломал над условием как написать и тут такое !!!

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinovich - Андрей (ничего, что без отчества?), определение параметров функции (в данном случае - конструктора) in-line или заранее - это вопрос стиля. Не переживайте, старайтесь писать код как можно проще и помнить о физике процесса. Успехов в программировании.

Comment: отчество тут само прилепилось как то )) хорошо... спасибо еще раз за помощь! Вам тоже всего хорошего... с наступающим :)